# Why won't this variable set in the for loop while using ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION?

Tags: windows, variables, command-line, batch-file

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set seed=-1
echo seed init val:%seed%

for %%f in (*.txt) DO (
    checksum %%f %seed%
    echo error level: !ERRORLEVEL!
    set seed = !ERRORLEVEL!
    echo new seed val:!seed!
)
```

Output:

```
C:\>returnval
seed init val:-1
Seed in main : FFFFFFFF
The 32-bit checksum for result.txt is 44DD58EE
error level: 1155356910
new seed val:-1 //still -1 ?? should be 1155356910
Seed in main : FFFFFFFF
The 32-bit checksum for test.txt is E245740F
error level: -498764785
new seed val:-1
```

The line that sets seed = ERRORLEVEL does not work.
to echo the ERRORLEVEL I did need to use the "!" otherwise it would not expand and display properly.

As you can see when we get to new seed value: it is still -1

How do I set `seed` to the last `ERRORVALUE`?

(Side note, the for loop is just looking up two text files I have and feeding it to an exe that returns a checksum for the file., that seems to works fine, as the ERRORLEVEL is the result of the exe.)

**Answer:** needed to use /a on the set to get the seed to take the numeric value of ERRORLEVEl and then use the "!" for the checksum parameter seed as well.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set seed=-1
echo seed init val:%seed%

for %%f in (*.txt) DO (
    checksum %%f !seed!
    echo error level: !ERRORLEVEL!
    set /a seed = !ERRORLEVEL!
    echo new seed val:!seed!
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know that you need to use delayed expansion for this to work properly, so it should be `set seed = !ERRORLEVEL!`. And `echo seed value: !seed!` when printing it out. The rule of thumb: if it's in a loop, then you have to delay the expansion.

Comment: Yes, i had tried that too but no luck, see updated code and result copied and pasted as is...thanks though.....

Comment: You also need to use `set seed=!errorlevel!` otherwise you're creating a variable named `seed ` (note the trailing space) with a value that starts with a space.